# Can Netsuite suitescript 1.0 API interact with backbone js

Tags: backbone.js, netsuite, suitescript

we are building netsuite CRM module using netsuite suitescript 1.0 api which interact with raw javascript , can we use backbone js /or some javascript framework to meet the same task

Answer (score 1):

I've used jQuery in the past by just adding it as a library on other scripts.  So, I'm sure backbone can be used as well.  If you are willing to use the current SuiteScript 2.0, here is the documentation for creating the custom modules in NetSuite.

[Create a Custom Module](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/44323)

Comment: Yes, just seconding this sentiment. You can absolutely include Backbone or any other JS library in your SuiteScripts; I've leveraged everything from Backbone to moment.js to arboreal.js. Just upload the relevant library's source file to the file cabinet, then use the Libraries tab on your Script record.

Comment: jQuery is actually already loaded by Netsuite, so you can just use it (via the `jQuery` variable) without adding any extra libraries.

Comment: could you provide me some use case where using jquery /backbone or some other javascript framework will make code more effective , as my purpose is solved with plain javascript but my organisation is asking me to leverage backbone.

Comment: Can ext. libraries be used in suitescript 1.0?